# Colocar el color para el active/hover del navbar dinámicamente vía Input() en Angular

Tags: angular

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web con Angular v11 y [bootstrap v4.6](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/).

Tengo un componente que será re-utilizable por muchos, se encarga de pintar un navbar, recibiendo el arreglo de items que tendrá el menú y el color que se usará para el active/hover.

Componente:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar-sub-category',
  templateUrl: './navbar-sub-category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar-sub-category.component.scss']
})
export class NavbarSubCategoryComponent {

  @Input() items: INavbarSubCategoryItem[];

}
```

SCSS:

```
.navbar-custom {
  margin: -1.25rem -1.25rem;
  background-color: #F1EBEB;
}

/* change the link color */
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #868898;
}

/* change the color of active or hovered links */
.navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-custom .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
  color: #F00073;
}
```

Template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-sm justify-content-center">

  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let m of items">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="m.route">{{m.title}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Queda pendiente recibir el color que se usará como el hover/active, cosa que no he podido lograr.

**He intentado:**

Componente:

```
@Input() activeColor: 'pink' | 'blue';
```

SCSS:

```
/* change the color of active or hovered links */
.pink {
  .navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
  .navbar-custom .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
    color: #F00073;
  }
}
```

Pensé también pasar el código del color (HEX), pero, no se cómo colocarlo en el SCSS dinámicamente.

Mi objetivo es pasar vía el `Input()` el color (o clase para tomar el color) del **hover/active** que tendrán los menus.

Answer (score 0):

con `@Input` tienes que darle un nombre a la variable que recibes:

```
@Input() color = 'pink' // <-- aqui solo el predeterminado
```

de esta forma llamas al componente pasandole el color:

```
<app-navbar-sub-category [color]="blue"></app-navbar-sub-category> // <-- aqui cambiarias el pink predeterminado a blue.
```

una vez recibes el color, que sera el nombre de la clase, lo puedes aplicar con `ngClass`, de esta manera:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-sm justify-content-center" [ngClass]="{'pink': color === 'pink', 'blue': color === 'blue'}">
```

y asi en cualquier parte donde quieras aplicar la clase que recibes por `@Input`.

espero haberte ayudado con esto.

***añadido****

el :hover es un complemento de la clase que sa activa al pasar el raton por encima. si lo que necesitas es que se ponga `pink` solo cuando pases por encima, yo crearia una clase nueva por ejemplo `.pinkOnOver:hover{background-color:pink}` y le asignas con ngClass a los componentes que no tengan la clase 'pink'(que ya estan con fondo rosa) de la misma manera:

```
[ngClass]="{'pinkOnOver': color === 'pink', 'blueOnOver': color === 'blue'}"
```

las etiquetas que tengan esa clase se pondran con fondo rosa(o azul) al pasar por encima, independientemente de las demas clases que tengan.

para el `.active` yo en concreto utilizo una "receta propia" porque nunca me he llevado bien con los ::ngdeep.

yo lo que hago es crear una variable de seleccion de categoria, y asigno la clase de seleccion con ngClass segun esa variable.

```
var selectedCategory: string;
```

luego le pongo un evento `(click)` en el elemento html seleccionable, `(click)="selectedCategory='coches'" //por ejemplo

y luego le aplico el `NgClass` quedando el elemento de esta manera:

```
   <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let m of items" [ngClass]="{'pinkOnOver': color === 'pink' && selectedCategory == 'coches', 'blueOnOver': color === 'blue' && selectedCategory == 'coches'}" (click)="selectedCategory = 'coches'">
```

seguro que no es lo mas elegante del mundo, pero resuelve el problema

Comment: Mi problema actual es que no se como asignarle el color a la clase `.navbar-custom .nav-item:hover .nav-link`. Usando ngClass solo puedo activar o desactivar clases regulares, pero y para un hover/active? para cambiar el color del mismo? Ese es mi actual problema.

Comment: edito la respuesta, que me estoy alargando mucho en el comentario..